# WPF change itemscontrol textbox item according to another control

Tags: wpf

I have an ItemsControl bound to a collection of some objects
in the ItemsControl's ItemTemplate i have a textbox bound to firstName
i want to add an asterisk to the firstName textbox text
when another textblock of comment is updated

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the 'comment' is information in item level or globaly, And from what source update of the "mystery" textBlock (not better to binding directly?)
But anyway if you need an asterisk as part of binding string (otherwise, in seperate element, its possible with a trigger to hide\visible), you need use `MultiBinding` with `Converter`:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <local:IsCommentConverter />
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        <Binding ElementName="txtBlockComment" Path="Text" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Very simple converter:

```
public class IsCommentConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var firstName =  (string)values[0];
        var commnet = (string)values[1];

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(commnet) ? firstName : firstName + "*";

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```